Change recursive into iterative function
I got a recursive function for exporting information and I want to transform it into an iterative one for efficiency reasons (toy problem below). However, as there are statements in the recursive function after the call of the recursive function, I do not obtain a working iterative solution.
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int n = 100;
int iMax = 2;

void fRecursive(int x)
{
    int u = 2 * x + 1;
    cout << u - 10 << ": ";

    if (u > n)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; ++i)
    {
        cout << u << "-" << i << "  "; 
        fRecursive(u);
        cout << "break" << endl;
    }
}

void fIterative(int x0)
{
    std::stack<int> myStack;
    myStack.push(x0);

    while (!myStack.empty())
    {
        int curx = myStack.top();
        myStack.pop();

        int u = 2 * curx + 1;
        cout << u - 10 << ": ";
        if (u > n)
            continue;

        for (int i = 0; i < iMax; ++i)
        {
            myStack.push(u);
            cout << u << "-" << i << "  ";

            cout << "break\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x0 = 10;

    cout << "Start Recursion" << endl;
    fRecursive(x0);
    cout << "End Recursion" << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Start Iterative" << endl;
    fIterative(x0);
    cout << "End Iterative" << endl << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

I managed to change recursive to iterative functions when there is no code block after the call of the recursive function, but did not manage to do so when this function is there.

I usually do not "convert" algorithms. I understand what the algorithm is trying to solve and implement new code.  There is no automated way, and maybe a using a stack isn't all that great either. Here is something that you can read: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/factorial-recursion-to-iteration

The way it is coded the iterative version may not be that much more efficient than the recursive one (if at all). It is certainly more opaque. Evaluating a polynomial is a more frequent and concrete example where iterative method(s) win out over recursive ones.

@PepijnKramer Well, there is an "automated"/"mechanical" way, since you can always replace the call-stack with a std::vector (or some actual stack container) and basically do the same thing as the recursive implementation by emulating the recursion. However, I definitely agree on the part where this is not a viable solution, and that the whole thing should be reexamined -- or kept as a recursive thing if there's no good solution and no actual benefit from making it non-recursive (like only having a small stack and running into overflows).

My rule: the maximum recursion depth for a recursive function shall be O(log n). If the depth is O(log n) like in this example, recursive method is typically best. However, having a O(n) depth would be asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big n. And this type of recursive function can be very easily converted to a loop, that is easier to understand, easier to debug, safer and faster.

As a general solution you could mimic pushing the state on the stack. The relevant context you need includes also the value of i, so you could stack pairs of x and i. In some practical scenarios (like this toy example) you might find ways to do it without that additional element on the stack, but I believe for the more generic approach you'd want to have that i (or whatever you iterate with) stacked as well.
Here is how that would look for your example:
#include <tuple>

void fIterative(int x) {
    std::stack<std::pair<int, int>> myStack;

    while (true) {
        int u = 2 * x + 1, i = 0;
        std::cout << u - 10 << ": ";
        myStack.push({u, 0});
        
        while (true) {
            std::tie(x, i) = myStack.top(); // or [x, i] = ... C++17
            myStack.pop();
            if (i < iMax && x <= n) {
                break;
            }
            if (myStack.empty()) {
                return;
            }
            std::cout << "break" << std::endl;
        }        
        std::cout << x << "-" << i << "  "; 
        myStack.push({x, i+1});
    }
}


As a sidenote, I generally don't use std::pair or std::tuple -- I prefer classes with members that have descriptive names, rather than "first" and "second". Your case is even worse since both have the same type -- so the compiler can't do anything if you accidentally mix up your use of "first" and "second".
